Inheriting annotation from an interface method to implemented methods of class
I'm writing an Aspect code to execute advice on a method which has particular annotation(metric in myCase) declared on top of it.
Create a custom annotation
package A;

public @interface Metric {

}

Create an interface
package application;

public interface TestInterface {

    @Metric
    void inheritMethod();
}
    

TestClass implements TestInterface
package application;

public class TestClass implements TestInterface {

    void inheritMethod() {
         
        // Definition continues
   }

}
    

Now I'm looking to find a way that @Metric annotation will be inherited into TestClass method(or any other implemented classes) and that will help me to satisfy my pointcut expression below and run the specific advice on all the implemented methods of inheritMethod.
example  @Pointcut("within(@com.abc.A.Metric *)") I'm considering to use for advice.
The problem is I don't want to place annotation in both declaration and as well in implementation class.
My Expectation is to write once in interface will help me to inherit somehow for implemented classes. Right now Java doesn't allow that annotations on interfaces to be inherited.

Method annotation inheritance simply does not exist as a concept in the JVM. See my native AspectJ workaround, which might be overkill for a beginner. In that case, you need to find another way to solve your problem. Wishing for some imagined functionality to exist does not make it true.-

@kriegaex - Do you think, writing some kind of custom annotation processor, which helps to find the implemented methods of super method that has annotation on top  and rewriting the class file during compile time with annotation. my thought is this way it will trigger Aspect and advice accordingly just by annotation.

That would be more complicated than my AspectJ solution. But feel free to do whatever you please.
